# How can I make photo CDs from iPhoto?

Tags: macos, dvd, burning, compact-disc, iphoto

I have a new MacBook. I don't know the OS, but just got it; it's the cheaper model.  I saved a lot of photos on [iPhoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhoto) and can't figure out how to burn a CD. I tried the "share" function and when I choose a location to save the photos and hit burn I get an error message that says can't create in that location. It needs to be run on a PC or photo processing place.

Answer (score 2):

Burn the disc using the Finder instead of iPhoto.

1. In the Finder, insert a blank CD or DVD. Your disc will show up on your desktop as a Burn Folder.

   [image]
2. Open iPhoto.
3. Select the Album(s) you wish to burn to disc.
4. Choose File > Export.
5. Click the File Export tab.
6. Choose a format from the Format pop-up menu.
     Note: Depending on the source of the images, you may want to select JPEG to ensure compatibility.
7. Configure the Size and Name options that you want. Make sure the "Use extension" or "Use filename" option is selected.
8. Click Export.
9. Select the Burn Folder you created to save the exported photos to and click OK.
10. Quit iPhoto when the export has completed.
11. From your desktop, open your disc's Burn folder and select the "Burn" button (as seen below).

    [image]

> taken from [Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1257)

**OR**

From iPhoto:

1. Open iPhoto and under the View menu select Show in Toolbar -> Burn and burn icon will appear on the bottom of iPhoto
2. Choose the album you want to burn on the Left panel.
3. Click the burn icon in the lower right of iPhoto.